# I'm trying to convert binary to decimal

Tags: c

ok... the logic is..  I'm passing an integer variable having binary number... say (11010101) which is 213 in decimal....

the function will find the number of digits of the binary number which is 8.Then it will run a loop that many times..  then if kth digit of that binary number is 1 then it'll add 2^k to ans variable if kth digit of the binary number is 0... I'll just skip it..

so  1     =128 1     =64 0     =0 1     =16 0     =0 1     =4 0     =0 1     =1
      ------
       213
      ------

Thats the logic....but wheni run it... I keep getting the answer as
0... Can u guys help me out??

So here is the code..

```
int toDecimal(int number,int base){
    if (base==2) {
        int i, n=number, dec=0, d1, d=0;

        while(n!=0){
            n=n/10;
            ++d;
        }
        d1=d;

        for(i=0;i<d;i++){
            if(n%10==1){
                dec+=pow(2,--d1);
                n=n/10;
            }
            else{
                --d1;
                n=n/10;
            }
        }
        return dec;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: General recommendation: Longer variable names do not cost more. It is far easier to understand what say `number_of_digits` represents than it is to understand what `d` represents.

Comment: you have to reset `n` after finding the number of digits.

Comment: @sharath gr8...point taken.. thanks for the tip :) .... so did u find why i keep getting 0??

Comment: Dealing with power of 2, you better make it with shift operation instead of pow, which is far more expensive.

Comment: SO is not a side for code review, what is your question?

Comment: what's the value of `n` after `while(n!=0)`? and then you calculate the modulo of it.

Comment: @mch thanks man...but i got wrong ans...  i got 171...but i should get 213

Comment: @mch    I've called the function like  toDecimal(11010101,2)  it should return 213

Comment: "an integer variable having binary number" is not a thing. An integer variable holds a number, it doesn't have any representation - it's not binary, it's not decimal.

Comment: you do this the wrong direction. you should do `dec+=1<i;` instead of pow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; number != 0; i++){
    if(number % 10 == 1){
        dec += 1<<i;
    }
    number /= 10;
}
```

this should solve all problems discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are permanently modifying n in your very first while loop with this statement: `n=n/10;` You need to set n back to number in between the loops with `n=number;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful hint:

- The binary representation of 171 is: **0b10101011**
- The binary representation of 213 is: **0b11010101**

Note that they have the same representation except that they are reversed.

That being said, because you count decimal places and everything else in your solution, it becomes pretty complicated. It doesn't need to be that complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int toDecimal(int number, int base) {
    assert(base == 2);
    int result = 0;
    int offset = 1;

    while (number) {
        if (number % 10 == 1)
            result += offset;
        offset *= 2;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", toDecimal(11010101, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two loop in the use only one loop like given below

and you can even eliminate the if statement.

```
int toDecimal(int number,int base){
    if (base==2) {
        int n=number, dec=0, d=0, r;

        while(n!=0){
            r=n%10;
            dec+=r*1<<d++;
            n=n/10;
        }
        return dec;
    }
    return 0;
}
```